# ASP development after SQL Server goes down?

Tags: testing, sql-server-2005, asp-classic, resources, loss

Scenario: ISS 8.5 is on our work machines, our Microsoft SQL Server is currently down for an indeterminate amount of time, and we don't have a back-up. We can continue to develop code on `localhost`. Because SQL Server is down, we can't execute any data transactions. Are there any reliable resources online to, at least, test if the developed SQL syntax is correct?

**Edit:** I will go ahead and eat my words. I had presumed that we were not allowed to install `SQL Server Express` locally. That was a bad guess. After I had sent our boss the suggestion from **marc_s**, he gave us the go-ahead. Now we have a back-up plan. For the record, the SQL Server is now online.

Comment: Install a copy of SQL Server Express locally?

Comment: I've asked and that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You must have access to another SQL server in order to test code against a SQL server. Your only options are to install SQL server on local machines, install SQL server on a local networked computer, or use a SQL server installed at a third party host.

Comment: As it currently stands, the first two options are out. Which leaves the third: "use a SQL server installed at a third party host".